Records not yet detected for custom domain
I want to use custom domain from squarespace.com for my Flutter app hosted with Firebase.
I updated DNS records as instructed, and more than 24 hours passed, but I still see warning, when I click button 'Verify' for both quick and advanced setup:
Records not yet detected (Last checked 2 minutes ago)
It can take up to 24 hours for changes to propagate. You can close this dialog for now and check again later.

This is what i have in DNS settings at squarespace.com:

This is what i see in firebase:


I replaced host in each record with @ and things worked out almost immediately.
